# Proxy settings in Android Studio 1.5

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio version 1.5 and I tried to create a new project, but I get this error:

```
Error:Connection timed out: connect. If you are behind an HTTP proxy, please configure the proxy settings either in IDE or Gradle.
```

I don't use a proxy and my Android Studio is in its default settings.

So what can the problem be?

---

Hint: I'm using a Wi-Fi internet connection

Comment: Don't you really use a proxy? Please, check connection settings in Internet Explorer. If I use Wi-Fi (without proxy), everything is fine.

Comment: i have the same problem, i am online as loading android studio but its yet. how can i solve it?